# converting xml data to array in cakephp

Tags: php, xml, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

i am using the predefined function XML component of cakephp.what i want to do is, to convert xml file data into an array for processing purpose. fot this my code is like:

```
App::import('Helper', 'Xml');
$xml = new XmlHelper();
$xml_data = & new XML($filePath);
$array = Set::reverse($xml_data);
```

This code is working perfectly if my xml file contains data in format:

```
<parent>
  <tag ...../>
  <tag ...../>
</parent>
```

where  is root node.

i.e all the tags are within a single parent tag.

But **the problem occurs when data is distributed in several different parent tags** i.e:

```
<parent>
  <tag ...../>
</parent>
<parent>
  <tag ...../>
</parent>
```

In this case only the data from the first parent tag is given in the output array.
I know that a xml file should have only 1 root node, but the problem is that while i am reading a xml file sometimes i get files with multiple root nodes.
**What i just want to know is that is there any way to read a xml file with multiple root nodes.**

**Is this any other way using which i can read multiple parent tags in a xml file**

Comment: Why was this down-voted? It's a legitimate question even if it lacks a bit of information that might help. Down-voters, at the very least explain why you're down-voting so that the person asking the question might at least in theory learn something from the experience.

Answer (score 0):

Are those parent-elements at the root of the XML document? That matters because XML only allows one root node. Under the root node, you can have as many elements as you want. It is not clear from your question whether the <parent>s are root nodes or sub-nodes of the root node.

But what you're trying to do may also be a bad idea unless you can be certain that the XML files will forever remain very small. Large, deep arrays in PHP can quickly become quite slow. Let me suggest learning XPath instead, which is a "sub-language" of a sorts to search for things in an XML document. XML processing in general tends to be somewhat slow and heavy, but large, deep PHP arrays can get extremely slow, no matter how you handle them.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I am not aware of any tool that allows you to read multiple root nodes. - If you're getting XML files with multiple root nodes, they are essentially flawed. The correct way to handle that would be to notify those who give you those XML files, telling them that they need to be valid XML.

The only alternative solution I can think of is manually splitting them up with some custom-made utility and then reading multiple files. But they really should just be valid XML to begin with.

Comment: Also note that EVEN IF you get this to work in this case, then most other XML parsers will fail with multiple root nodes. That defeats the purpose of using XML in the first place. I cannot stress this enough; those who gave you those files should have the responsibility of giving you valid XML.